# how to implement two fonts in one Java AWT without disturbing the font size? whenever i put second font style it will be an error

Tags: java, awt

```
    LabTask2(){
    Frame f= new Frame();  
    Label label = new Label();   
    Label label1 = new Label("PROGRAMMING IS EASY");
    label1.setBounds(170,250,170,20 );
    label1.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font. BLACK ,13));
    label1.setForeground(Color. BLACK); 
    }
```

As you can see here i can only put `Font.Black`as i want to add `Font.ITALIC`but cannot because it will appear as an error.

Comment: Java AWT? Unless you traveled back to the 1990's, you shouldn't be writing code strictly in AWT.

Comment: it is part of my diploma course, I did not know much about it too,but we also currently studying visual basic,almost look simlar to AWT

Comment: this is actually part of a current course????? I started college in 2000, even then it was to out of date to be in the curriculum. Hate to tell you, but it doesn't seem your course will be worth all that much.

Comment: anyway, have you tried something like this: new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 12) ?

Comment: thanks for the help. even my lecturer did not know how to use it and we basically had to search it online by ourselves every time.we currently also studying using android studio. is it old stuff?

Comment: android studio? No. Android Studio is pretty new. It was announced over a decade after AWT had been replaced with Swing, and even after there was already something to replace Swing

Comment: currently,do you know what language is kind of fresh and new that i can maybe learn?